# Insert data based on data count from another table

Tags: sql

How can I insert the data based on data count from another table in SQL?

`Store` table:

```
StoreCode   StoreName
-----------------------
   HQ       HQ Mini Mart    
   BT       BT Mini Mart
```

`Stock` table:

```
ID  | StkID | StockName | Price
----+-------+-----------+-------
 1  | 1001  | Avocado   | 10
 2  | 1002  | Apple     |  2
```

Expected result

```
StoreCode   StkID   StockName   Price
--------------------------------------
HQ            1     Avocado       10
BT            1     Avocado       10
HQ            2     Apple          2
BT            2     Apple          2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cross join -

```
select StoreCode,ID,StockName,Price 
from Store cross join Stock
```

Comment: Aliases would be really nice here ^ ^